# Perl : How to search a Indefinite list of keywords from a list of files in a folder

Tags: perl

Can anyone help me with Perl Script on below problem:

File1.txt -> with keywords to search

```
Hello_ 
World!
+Bye
Temp-
```

File2 (Can be of any extension) In which Keywords to search for, File3, File4 ....

I want to search for all the keywords from File1 in File2, and If they are found then print the keyword found along with the file number and line number In which this particular keyword is found.

I want to keep these no of keywords and files to be indefinite - they can be added and modified.

```
open(MYINPUTFILE, "<expressions.txt");
# open for input

my(@lines) = <MYINPUTFILE>;
#print @lines;

my @files = grep ( -f ,<*main_log>,<*Project>);

$n = 0;
$l = 0;
#foreach my$file (@files) {
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    my @f = grep /$line/,@files;
    print "@f\n";
}
#}
}
```

Issue - I tried to execute the above code but It does not print anything on my command prompt. I am using Windows 7

Comment: Welcome to the site. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried the below code but It does not give me the output i want

Comment: # open(MYINPUTFILE, "<expressions.txt"); # open for input
# my(@lines) = <MYINPUTFILE>; 
# #print @lines;

 # my @files = grep ( -f ,<*main_log>,<*Project>);
   # $n = 0;
   # $l = 0;

   # #foreach my$file (@files){
   
   # foreach my $line(@lines)
   # {
   # my @f = grep /$line/,@files;
   # print "@f\n";
   # }
   
   
   # #}

# }

Comment: For future reference, you can edit your question to make changes, like I have to include the code

Comment: Are the files in your example all named e.g. 'mymail_log','123Project' etc.? Because it looks like you maybe try to get files from a folder. Please test if your `@files` really contains the files you want to use for the keyword search.

Comment: Also you're looking for the keywords in the filenames only. If you wish to search the _content_ of your files, you have to either open each of them yourself and go through the lines, or use something like File::Grep.

Comment: yes, It does contain the file named main_log Inside the Folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on your posted code:

```
use strict; # always use these
use warnings; 

open( my $kw, '<', 'expressions.txt') or die $!;
my @keywords = <$kw>;
chomp(@keywords); # remove newlines at the end of keywords

# get list of files in current directory
my @files = grep { -f } (<*main_log>,<*Project>);

# loop over each file to search keywords in
foreach my $file (@files) {
  open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
  my @content = <$fh>;
  close($fh);
  my $l = 0;
  foreach my $kw (@keywords) {
    my $search = quotemeta($kw); # otherwise keyword is used as regex, not literally
    foreach (@content) { # go through every line for this keyword
      $l++;
      printf 'Found keyword %s in file %s, line %d:%s'.$/, $kw, $file, $l, $_
        if /$search/;
    }
  }
}
```

Regarding the questions in the comments below:

The innermost loop just counts for line numbers `$l++` and puts out the finds in case of occurence - the `if /$search/` is still part of the statement above. It could also be written as

```
if ( /$search/ ) {
  printf ...
}
```

The [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) is used to format the output. You could have also done this by simple using `print` and concatinate all the needed variables. I just prefer it this way.

This assumes, that you want a list of found lines per keyword for every file. You have to switch the order and logic for `@keywords` and `@content` to get it line ordered.

For additional functionality regarding comments in the keyword file, you would have to postprocess the content to discern the search terms from comments. Possibly in a hash with search term as key and comment as value. Then you could use only the hash keys for the search (see innermost loop) and put out the comment, if existing, as additional line.

Comment: I intentionally used 'keyword first' in this example, since no preference was given in the question. If the OP wants it 'line number first' ordered, he can adopt the change easily. The principle should be clear.

Comment: I am not able to search more than one keyword if put under expressions.txt like below e.g. Hello world bye ... longsting all in new line treating as separate keywords

Comment: I'm sorry, the keywords array still contained the newlines at the end. Fixed it by `chomp`ing...

Comment: It works fine now .. can you please help to explain the below line printf 'Found keyword %s in file %s, line %d:%s'.$/, $kw, $file, $l, $_

Comment: What If I want to add a comment In the keywords In square brackets to print separately but not as part of search e.g. Hello World [This Is just welcome message] Hello World should be the keyword but text under square brackets should be the comments displayed when found this keyword.

Comment: What If I want to add a comment In the keywords In square brackets to print separately but not as part of search e.g. Hello World [This Is just welcome message] Hello World should be the keyword but text under square brackets should be the comments displayed when found this keyword.