# How to get a comment printed for each line of text that matches within a file?

Tags: perl

I am trying to match a keyword/text/line given in a file called `expressions.txt` from all files matching `*main_log`. When a match is found I want to print the comment for each line that matches.

Is there any better way to get this printed?

```
expression.txt
Hello World ! # I want to print this comments#
Bye* #I want this to print when Bye Is match with main_log#
:::
:::
```

Below Is the code I used :

```
{
    open( my $kw, '<', 'expressions.txt' ) or die $!;
    my @keywords = <$kw>;
    chomp( @keywords ); # remove newlines at the end of keywords

    # get list of files in current directory
    my @files = grep { -f } ( <*main_log>, <*Project>, <*properties> );

    # loop over each file to search keywords in
    foreach my $file ( @files ) {

        open( my $fh, '<', $file ) or die $!;
        my @content = <$fh>;
        close( $fh );

        my $l = 0;

        foreach my $kw ( @keywords ) {

            my $search = quotemeta( $kw ); # otherwise keyword is used as regex, not literally

            #$kw =~ m/\[(.*)\]/;
            $kw =~ m/\((.*)\)/;
            my $temp = $1;
            print "$temp\n";

            foreach ( @content ) { # go through every line for this keyword
                $l++;
                printf 'Found keyword %s in file %s, line %d:%s'.$/, $kw, $file, $l, $_ if /$search/;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried this code to print the comments mentioned within parentheses `(...)` but it is not printing in the fashion which I want like below:

If the expression.txt contains

```
Hello World ! # I want to print this comments#
```

If `Hello World !` string is matched in my file called `main_log` then it should match only `Hello World!` from the `main_log` but print `# I want to print this comments#` as a comment for user to understand the keyword.

These keywords can be from any length or contains any character.

It worked fine but just a little doubt on printing the required output Into a file though I have used perl -w Test.pl > my_output.txt command on command prompt not sure how can I use Inside the perl script Itself

```
open( my $kw, '<', 'expressions.txt') or die $!;
my @keywords = <$kw>;
chomp(@keywords); # remove newlines at the end of keywords


# post-processing your keywords file
my $kwhashref = {
  map {
    /^(.*?)(#.*?#)*$/;
    defined($2) ? ($1 => $2) : ( $1 => undef )
  } @keywords
}; 


# get list of files in current directory
my @files = grep { -f } (<*main_log>,<*Project>,<*properties>);


# loop over each file to search keywords in
foreach my $file (@files) {
  open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
  my @content = <$fh>;
  close($fh);
  my $l = 0;
  #foreach my $kw (@keywords) {

  foreach my $kw (keys %$kwhashref) {
    my $search = quotemeta($kw); # otherwise keyword is used as regex, not literally
    #$kw =~ m/\[(.*)\]/;
    #$kw =~ m/\#(.*)\#/;
    #my $temp = $1;
    #print "$temp\n";

    foreach (@content) { # go through every line for this keyword
      $l++;
      if (/$search/)
      {

      # only print if comment defined
      print $kwhashref->{$kw}."\n" if defined($kwhashref->{$kw}) ;    
      printf 'Found keyword %s in file %s, line %d:%s'.$/, $kw, $file, $l, $_
      #printf '$output';

      }


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Do you get an error, or does your code do something you don't want and you don't know why? Please be specific. You can [edit] your question and add details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code has mismatched braces `{ ... }` and won't compile.

If you were to add another closing brace to the end of your code then it would compile, but the line

```
 $kw =~ m/\((.*)\)/;
```

will never succeed since there are no parentheses anywhere in `expressions.txt`. If a match has not succeeded then the value of `$1` will be retained from the most recently successful regex match operation

You are also trying to search the lines from the files against the whole of the lines retrieved from `expressions.txt`, when you should be splitting those lines into keywords and their corresponding comments

Comment: Actually It was a typo to miss {

Comment: regarding () In the expression I have added them now .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the followup for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934916/perl-how-to-search-a-indefinite-list-of-keywords-from-a-list-of-files-in-a-fol/41937591#41937591) of another question of you. What I tried to suggest in the last paragraph would start after the first three lines of your code:

```
# post-processing your keywords file
my $kwhashref = {
  map {
    /^(.*?)(#.*?#)*$/;
    defined($2) ? ($1 => $2) : ( $1 => undef )
  } @keywords
};
```

Now you have the keywords in a hashref containing the actual keywords to search for as keys, and comments as values, if they exists (using your `#comment#` at the end of line syntax here).

Your keyword loop would now have to use `keys %$kwhashref` and you now can additionally print the comment in the inner loop, converted like shown in the answer I linked. The additional print:

```
print $kwhashref->{$kw}."\n" if defined($kwhashref->{$kw}); # only print if comment defined
```

Comment: It worked fine now .. just added the complete code above also what If I want to print the out put to a file ..here are multiple Printf

Comment: Just a small doubt .. how can I let me keywords to search In a order rather than In random order.. Like if there are keywords in my text file Hello World Bye..and In all the files I want to start with Hello followed by World and then by Bye ..